# amChart 'countries visited' map - how to make mobile responsive

Tags: responsive, amcharts

How can I make the 'countries visited' map mobile responsive? It shows fine on PC, but the map is off the page on a mobile/smartphone. You cant even slide the map over.

I got the HTML for the map from https://www.amcharts.com/visited_countries/

I'm a novice not a coder, so not sure if there is code that can be added to make the map mobile responsive. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive? I'm on mobile and can interact with that just fine.

Comment: Mobile Responsive means that the element displays in full on mobile phones (or smartphones) and is fully interactive. So if you look at my webpage on your phone, most of the map is off the screen.  www.travelgroove.com.au/countries-visited

Comment: Ah I see. Well you'll need to include the css you used in your question because the amcharts.com version is definitely ok, so it'll be specific to your implementation.

Comment: Sorry, that answer doesnt help me. I used the html code from their website (as per the link I gave in original post). So it doesnt display well on my website, but it displays  ok on their website. So I need to know what do I add to that html code to make it work on my website? I cant contact them as I'm not a paying customer.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation this is what worked for me. I used the video container CSS code from [here](https://flaviocopes.com/responsive-youtube-videos/) which is used to make embedded videos responsive.
Then I edited the div line from amCharts from:

```html
<div id="mapdiv" style="width: 775px; height: 450px;"></div>
```

To:

```html
<div class="video-container" id="mapdiv" style="max-width: 775px; max-height: 450px;"></div>
```

Hope this can work for you.